# typescript function return undefined when calling the function in another class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, typescript2.0

In my **Angular 2** project I have this class:

```
export class ApiEnvConf {

    /**
     * @type {Object}
     */
    public _dev: {environnement: string, basePath: URL};

    /**
     * @type {Object}
     */
    public _staging: {environnement: string, basePath: URL};

    /**
     * @type {Object}
     */
    public _prod: {environnement: string, basePath: URL};

    constructor(){
        this._dev;
        this._staging;
        this._prod;
    }

    /**
     * @return {Object}
     */
    get devEnv(): {"environnement": string, "basePath": URL} {
        return this._dev;
    }

    /**
     * @return {Object}
     */
    get stagingEnv(): {"environnement": string, "basePath": URL} {
        return this._staging;
    }

    /**
     * @return {Object} 
     */
    get prodEnv(): {"environnement": string, "basePath": URL} {
        return this._prod;
    }

    /**
     * @param  {string} environnement
     * @param  {URL}    basePath
     * @return {Object}
     */
    set devEnv(newDevEnvArray: {environnement: string, basePath: URL}){
      this._dev = newDevEnvArray;
    }

    /**
     * @param  {string} environnement
     * @param  {URL}    basePath
     * @return {Object}
     */
    set stagingEnv(newStagingEnvArray: {environnement: string, basePath: URL}) {
      this._staging = newStagingEnvArray;
    }

    /**
     * @param  {string} environnement
     * @param  {URL}    basePath
     * @return {Object}
     */
    set prodEnv(newProdEnvArray: {environnement: string, basePath: URL}) {
      this._prod = newProdEnvArray;
    }
}
```

As you can see I export this class in order to use it in others files (other classes). Here's one example of file using this class:

```
import { Injectable, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { ApiEnvConf } from './api-env-conf-class';

@Injectable()
@Component({
  providers: [ ApiEnvConf ]
})
export class ImportConfig {

  /**
   * @type {ApiEnvConf}
   */
  public envParam = new ApiEnvConf();

  constructor(
    public http: Http
  ) {}

  loadEnvData() {
    this.http.get('assets/env-config/parameters.json')
    .map((res: Response) => (res.json()))
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.envParam  = this.instanciateApiEnvConfClass(data);
        return this.envParam;
      },
      err => {
          console.log("oops !");
          return err;
      }
    )
  }

  instanciateApiEnvConfClass(data: Object){
    let apiEnvConf = new ApiEnvConf();
    // set dev by calling getter of ApiEnvConf class
    apiEnvConf.devEnv = {
      environnement: data["dev"]["environnement"],
      basePath: new URL(data["dev"]["basePath"])
    };
    // set stagging by calling getter of ApiEnvConf class
    apiEnvConf.stagingEnv = {
      environnement: data["staging"]["environnement"],
      basePath: new URL(data["staging"]["basePath"])
    };
    // set prod by calling getter of ApiEnvConf class
    apiEnvConf.prodEnv = {
      environnement: data["prod"]["environnement"],
      basePath: new URL(data["prod"]["basePath"])
    };
    return apiEnvConf;
  }
}
```

So If you look into the `loadEnvData()` function, if I make a `console.log(this.envParam);` before the `return` **statement** I have this result in my console browser:

[image]

So my class ApiEnvConf is not empty and have all the properties I need.

The class ImportConfig is another class I use in many files to init the environnement configuration.

So in another class of another folder I have this class:

```
import { Injectable, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ImportConfig } from '../services/import-config';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
@Component({
  providers: [ ImportConfig ]
})
export class Test {
constructor(public http: Http, public config: ImportConfig) {
    this.config;
    this.check();
  }

  check() {
    let test = this.config.loadEnvData();
    console.log(test);
  }

  /*
    ...
    ...
    ...
  */
}
```

The output of the `console.log(test);` returns me **"undefined"**. Where am I wrong ?

Comment: What is `this.config;` supposed to do?

Comment: Try debugging your code, add a breakpoint in the loadEnvData and see line by line what is going on

Comment: `loadEnvData` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 3):

You have called an asynchronous function which doesn't return anything:

```
  loadEnvData(env: string = "dev") {
    this.http.get('assets/env-config/parameters.json')
    .map((res: Response) => (res.json()))
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.envParam  = this.instanciateApiEnvConfClass(data);
        return this.envParam;
      },
      err => {
          console.log("oops !");
          return err;
      }
    )
    // Note: *here* is where you would, in theory, return something
  }
```

When you call a function without an explicit `return`, it returns `undefined`. You've assumed this function is synchronous, which it isn't.

Your `loadEnvData` function should provide some callback mechanism to indicate completion; there you can access the loaded data.